# Is a trie equivalent to std::map<std::string, int> in C++?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, trie, space-complexity

Is the usual implementation of a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) equivalent to

`std::map<std::string, int>`

in C++?

By equivalence, I mean: do they have the same space complexity, and does their respective operation have the same time complexity?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I know they are fundamentally 2 different data structures. The question is about a comparison of space and time complexity

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe so. `std::map` and `std::set` are usually implemented as [red-black balanced binary trees](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)

Space complexity is much better in a prefix tree -- you're storing the common prefix to a whole bunch of strings in one consolidated place, whereas in a binary tree the whole string is stored in the node, so the prefix is repeated in each string that has it.

Time complexity for finds, inserts, removals is still average `O(log n)`. However, the constant factor is often important. Prefix trees generally trade for lower height but greater width. The specific application is important for choosing which one.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to return keys from the trie, you need to synthesize them from the nodes.  This is obviously an O(log N) operation in the number of nodes, O(N) in the length of the string.